# Watson Vision API suddenly triggers CORS errors

Tags: ibm-watson

After a year of using Watson's vision API from a browser sometime in the last few weeks a policy seems to have changed because browsers refuse to connect with messages such as:

> Failed to load https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classify?version=2016-05-19&api_key=...: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I don't want to create a proxy to work around this. Is there another way?

Comment: I will let the team know about this. They updated the service ~ December 2017

Comment: The team is working on adding CORS back. It will be there next Month along with some new features